# Initialize method with array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, initialization, arguments

im new with ruby and i tried to put an array into initialize method but its not work like that, so how to put an array with this argument ? thanks

```
class User
    attr_accessor :name, :friends

    def initialize(name, friends)
        @name = name
        @friends = friends
    end

    def friendNbr
        return friends.count
    end

    def isFriendWith(value)
        friends.each do |user|
            if (user.name == value)
                return "Yes, #{name} is friend with #{user.name}"
            end
        end

        return "No, #{name} is not friend with #{value}"
    end
end

jane = User.new("Jane", [boris, francois, carlos, alice])

bob = User.new("Bob", [jane, boris, missy])

alice = User.new("Alice", [bob, jane])


# bob.isFriendWith("Jane")
# jane.isFriendWith("Alice")
# alice.isFriendWith("Carlos")
```

Comment: There's a cyclic problem with your approach: you can't pass a user before creating it. For example, you pass `alice` as a friend to `jane` before creating `alice` – that doesn't work. You have to create the users first and once they are created, you can define the friendships.

Comment: ... BTW, does `bob.isFriendWith("Jane")` imply `jane.isFriendWith("Bob")`? In other words, is friendship something mutual or can it be one-sided?

Comment: "its not work like that" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, first sorry because i didn't describe my problem / error, yes the problem comes from the variable was not assigned, I am so confused because im coding with an DB/SQL approch, that's why it didn't work, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple ways of solving your problem :

- First `friends` could be array of names (string)

```
class User
    attr_accessor :name, :friends

    def initialize(name, friends)
        @name = name
        @friends = friends
    end

    def friendNbr
        return friends.count
    end

    def isFriendWith(value)
        friends.each do |friend_name|
            if (friend_name == value)
                return "Yes, #{name} is friend with #{friend_name}"
            end
        end

        return "No, #{name} is not friend with #{friend_name}"
    end
end

jane = User.new("Jane", ["Boris", "Francois", "Carlos", "Alice"])

bob = User.new("Bob", ['Jane', 'Boris', 'Missy'])

alice = User.new("Alice", ['Bob', 'Jane'])


bob.isFriendWith("Jane")
jane.isFriendWith("Alice")
alice.isFriendWith("Carlos")
```

- Other way is to pass object as you did but in this case you can only pass object already instanciated. In this second choice you can add a method `addFriend` and first create `User` and then add them `friends`.

```
class User
    attr_accessor :name, :friends

    def initialize(name, friends)
        @name = name
        @friends = friends
    end

    def friendNbr
        return friends.count
    end

    def isFriendWith(value)
        friends.each do |user|
            if (user.name == value)
                return "Yes, #{name} is friend with #{user.name}"
            end
        end

        return "No, #{name} is not friend with #{value}"
    end

    def addFriend(...)
      ...
    end

end

jane = User.new("Jane", [])

bob = User.new("Bob", [jane])

alice = User.new("Alice", [bob, jane])


bob.isFriendWith("Jane")
jane.isFriendWith("Alice")
alice.isFriendWith("Carlos")
```